# Auditing columns in Entity Framework

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

I need to add "auditing" columns to the tables of a database - columns such as "CreatedOn", "CreatedBy", "LastModifiedOn" and so on.

I came across two approaches - either add those columns to every table or add an "auditing" table for all the tables.

I would like to ask if there is any recommended solution for Entity Framework, either code-first or database-first. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this blog out: by Bilal Fazlani

http://bilal-fazlani.blogspot.in/2013/09/adding-log-audit-feature-to-entity.html

It contains the links to the nuget package and some instructions.

It seems to be the best I found at the moment.

In answer to your question: I don't believe there is a recommended solution per say.

Comment: Nice blog. Thank You!